# md5 inC++ with UTF16LE

Tags: python, c++, openssl, md5

I'm trying to transfer Python code to C++.

Is there a way to convert a string to UTF16LE and work with MD5 from OpenSSL?

I need this for the authentication with my router that supply smart home features.

This code works with normal strings (UTF8) fine, but I need UTF16LE because the result of the same string with UTF8 and UTF16LE is different:

```
string Crypto::getMD5(string stringToCrypt)
{
    unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char charArray[stringToCrypt.size()+1];

    char mdString[33];

    strcpy(charArray,stringToCrypt.c_str());
    MD5((unsigned char*)&charArray, strlen(charArray), (unsigned char*)&digest); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

    return mdString;
}
```

In Python I simply encode my string:

```
md5Hash = hashlib.md5()
md5Hash.update(input.encode('utf-16le'))
return md5Hash.hexdigest()
```

Comment: So the procedures for converting to and from UTF8 and UTF16 are well documented. It would probably take an hour or two to write your own code.

Comment: MD5 needs (unsigned char*), how I can handle this with a char16_t after I convert my string to a u16string?

Comment: MD5 just needs a bunch of bits to hash, so you can just cast the char16_t array (or pointer) to a unsigned char*.  You may also need to adjust the length i.e. string length * sizeof(char16_t)

Comment: Have you gotten it to work?

Comment: Hey, yes, sry a bit late, but i posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but this worked for me:

```
string Crypto::getMd5HashAsUtf16(string stringToHash)
{
    //convert input string(utf8) to utf16
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>,char16_t> wstringConverter; 
    u16string stringToCrypt16 = wstringConverter.from_bytes(stringToHash);    
    
    //create a char array
    char16_t bufferCharArr16[stringToCrypt16.size()+1];
    
    //fill char array from input string
    for(int i=0; i < stringToCrypt16.size(); i++)
    {
            bufferCharArr16[i] = stringToCrypt16.at(i);
    }
    
    //calc hash
    unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char mdString[33];

    MD5((unsigned char*)bufferCharArr16, stringToCrypt16.size()*sizeof(char16_t), (unsigned char*)&digest); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

    return mdString;
}
```